# Column 'student_id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: php

have a function get_autocomplete in model search

```
public function get_autocomplete()
    {
        $x = array();
        $search_data = "sah"; 
        $this->db->select('student_id,filename,random,type,mime');
        $this->db->from('uploads a');
        $this->db->or_like('filename',$search_data);
        $this->db->or_like('random',$search_data);
        $this->db->or_like('type',$search_data);
        $this->db->or_like('mime',$search_data);
        $this->db->join('student-record c', 'c.student_id=a.student_id', 'left');
        $this->db->like('name',$search_data);
        $this->db->or_like('email',$search_data);
        $this->db->or_like('phone',$search_data);
        $res   = $this->db->get();
    }
```

but I get error which states

> Error Number: 1052
>
> Column 'student_id' in field list is ambiguous
>
> SELECT `student_id`, `filename`, `random`, `type`, `mime` FROM (`uploads` a) LEFT JOIN `student-record` c ON
>   `c`.`student_id`=`a`.`student_id` WHERE `filename` LIKE '%sah%' OR
>   `random` LIKE '%sah%' OR `type` LIKE '%sah%' OR `mime` LIKE '%sah%'
>   AND `name` LIKE '%sah%' OR `email` LIKE '%sah%' OR `phone` LIKE
>   '%sah%'
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\ededge2\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Help me to recover this.

Comment: You given alias name 'a' for the table 'uploads'. So you have to represent the fields like a.student_id, a.filename, etc. Then try again

Comment: @Arun i tried but i get same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because both the `tables`(uploads,student-record) have `student_id` key in it.

When you use `JOIN` make sure you use alias to access the particular column in case of the both tables have similar column names.

So you can update your query like this,

```
public function get_autocomplete()
    {
        $x = array();
         $search_data = "sah"; 
        $this->db->select('a.student_id,filename,random,type,mime');
        $this->db->from('uploads a');
        $this->db->or_like('filename',$search_data);
        $this->db->or_like('random',$search_data);
        $this->db->or_like('type',$search_data);
        $this->db->or_like('mime',$search_data);
        $this->db->join('student-record c', 'c.student_id=a.student_id', 'left');
        $this->db->like('name',$search_data);
        $this->db->or_like('email',$search_data);
        $this->db->or_like('phone',$search_data);
        $res   = $this->db->get();
    }
```

> Column 'student_id' in field list is ambiguous,
> It means it doesn't know which column value it has to return, either from **uploads** or **student-record**.

---

**Update:**

```
$this->db->select('a.student_id,filename,random,type,mime,name,phone');
// add name and phone to get it in the result-set.
```

Comment: error is resolved but i get an arrayArray ( [0] => Array ( [student_id] => stud-123 [filename] => vid132323232323asasd [random] => skdjskdjskdj [type] => video [mime] => mp4 ) ) null

Comment: instead of Array ( [0] => Array ( [student_id] => stud-123 [filename] => vid132323232323asasd [random] => skdjskdjskdj [type] => video [mime] => mp4  [name] => sahad  [phone] => 8561016654) )

Comment: Then add phone and name to the select statement: `$this->db->select('a.student_id,filename,random,type,mime,name,phone')`

Comment: i used my query like this which give me expected resultpublic function get_autocomplete($search_data)
    {
        $search_data="vid";
      $res = $this->db->query("SELECT `student-record`.`student_id`,`student-record`.`name`,`student-record`.`email`, `uploads`.`filename`
FROM `student-record`
INNER JOIN `uploads`
where `name` REGEXP '$search_data' or `filename` REGEXP '$search_data'" );
      return ($res->result_array());    

    }thanks for support

Comment: Great, Please accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred when use same field name two table that we are join.To resolve this problem you should use like this when getting data "table_name.student_id as stu_id".your problem will be resolved and you access student_id by stu_id.